# JS not working in pc but works on JSFIddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code works perfectly in JSFiddle but its not working when I put it on a html file. I can't find the error by myself.

Here is the working link [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/G77Kb/)

And bellow is the code which is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#Checkbox1, #Checkbox2').on('change', function () {
    console.log();
    if ($('#Checkbox1').is(':checked') && $('#Checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
        $('#circle_2').css('background-color', '#999');
    } else {
        $('#circle_2').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    }
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">

#circle_2 {
    border:solid 1px #333;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
#circle {
    border:solid 1px #333;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.circle_text{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:37px;
    color:#333;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>


</head>

<body>
<!-- Circle 1-->
            <div id="position_1">
                <div id="circle">
                    <p class="circle_text">

                        #1
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Circle 2-->
            <div id="position_2">
                <div id="circle_2">
                    <p class="circle_text">

                        #2
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <br/><br/>

        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox1" name="Checkbox1"/> Answer one <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox2" name="Checkbox2"/> Answer two <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox3" name="a3"/> Answer three <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox4" name="a4"/> Answer four <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox5" name="a5"/> Answer five <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox6" name="a6"/> Answer six <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox7" name="a7"/> Answer seven <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox8" name="a8"/> Answer eight<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox9" name="a9"/> Answer nine <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox10" name="a10"/> Answer ten <br/>


</body>
</html>
```

I suspect I am missing something to load, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Check your console to see what the errors are.

Comment: Probably the code is running before those elements exist

Comment: It is "not working". How is it not working? What is not working?

Comment: I am using Dreamweaver as the editor and no error shows up.

Comment: Put your code just before body closing tag or DOM ready handler

Comment: @sushain97: When anyone checks the first 2 check box the Circle_2 [#2] should change color

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap your jQuery code in a [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Checkbox1, #Checkbox2').on('change', function () {
        console.log();
        if ($('#Checkbox1').is(':checked') && $('#Checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
            $('#circle_2').css('background-color', '#999');
        } else {
            $('#circle_2').css('background-color', 'transparent');
        }
    });
});
```

Or before the closing body tag. You're executing the code before the elements exist in the page. jsFiddle.net wraps your code in the document ready call automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your code executes when `<head>` is loaded, so the checkboxes don't exist yet. Use `$(document).ready()` to execute the code when the page has finished loading, or put the code element after the elements used in the code (inside `<body>`).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Checkbox1, #Checkbox2').on('change', function () {
        console.log();
        if ($('#Checkbox1').is(':checked') && $('#Checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
            $('#circle_2').css('background-color', '#999');
        } else {
            $('#circle_2').css('background-color', 'transparent');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Also, in JSFiddle there is an option in the left bar to execute the code in an `onLoad` handler. That is a default option, and it fixes your problem also. This explains it working in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle executes the code when document is ready, by itself. You've to add it on your local file.

Replace your Javascript with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Checkbox1, #Checkbox2').on('change', function () {
            console.log();
        if ($('#Checkbox1').is(':checked') && $('#Checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
            $('#circle_2').css('background-color', '#999');
        } else {
            $('#circle_2').css('background-color', 'transparent');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the jQuery code inside document ready function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#Checkbox1, #Checkbox2').on('change', function () {
    console.log();
    if ($('#Checkbox1').is(':checked') && $('#Checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
        $('#circle_2').css('background-color', '#999');
    } else {
        $('#circle_2').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    }
});
});
```

Also make sure that you have working internet connection because the jQuery library is loaded at run time from server. If you don't have internet then your code will not work.